# Best way to provide third party developers access to my code?

Tags: c#, design, programming-practices

Currently working on a project and facing a structure problem.

The app I'm developing communicate with hardware my company is building. We want to provide access to third party developer to our hardware but we want to keep data usage by our own (how many time the hardware is turn off/on, how many times the hardware is used by 100%, ...). We are having bad time choosing the best policy. Should we give them a dll - and loose access to this data, API (web service) - and lose access to hardware functionality or providing our own app that communicate with theirs?

Do you know a way to provide third party developers access to our hardware without giving up on data usage?

Comment: Your drivers are going to need to do everything and anything, but you can create an API through which they can use to call your drivers which has only a subset of that functionality.  It's certainly not foolproof, but have you ever tried writing your own drivers without any manual to go by?  It's practically unthinkable.

Comment: sounds like you need some test hardware

Comment: For example : we have a method in a C# dll that turn on our hardware. But if we provide this dll file we won't be able to know how many times the product was turn on ! Or we should call a web service from the dll that set the use count to +1 every time the dll method is called ?

Comment: @JohnWisthler: If I were a third-party developer wanting to interact with your hardware, would I get a sample to put on my desk, or would you give me a way to remotely interact with a sample that stays at your premises?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Of course, our third party customer had to register on our website and receive a free test hardware to develop and try.

Comment: Calling a web service each time your dll is called will lead developers to abandon both the dll and the hardware quickly.

Comment: Not necessarily every time is called. You could log the usage and send the log during the boot of before to be shutdown

Answer (score 1):

If you are providing hardware sampled to external parties, then your ability to monitor and track statistics on those hardware samples will be limited and largely dependent on the cooperation of the parties that you supply the samples to.

If your hardware contains a micro-processor and some non-volatile storage that can be written, then the best way to ensure that critical statistics are collected is to do it on the hardware itself. For reading those values, you can either read them out when the sample is returned to you or you can add a readout mechanism to the driver.

If your hardware is not capable of registering the statistics itself, then you can include that in the driver that the third-party developers use to communicate with the hardware.

Regardless of if the driver collects the statistics itself or if it reads them from the actual hardware, to get them to you can be done in two ways:

1. You ask the third-party developer to periodically read out the statistics and send them to you (which can be done by providing an executable that does this in one go), or
2. You add the capability of "phoning home" with the statistics to your driver. Then you should consider the possibility that your servers can't be reached (user is not connected to the internet; there is a firewall in-between that disallows the connection; etc.) and what consequences that should have.